# Bower list matching my dependencies versions

Tags: bower

Is there a way for `bower list` command to show updates available while respecting my dependencies versions

example bower.json :

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "<2"
    }
}
```

bower install :

```
bower installing jquery#1.10.0
```

jquery update to 1.10.1 (bower info jquery):

```
jquery

  Versions:
    - 2.0.2
    - 2.0.1
    - 2.0.0
    - 1.10.1
    - 1.10.0
```

bower list:

```
bower discover Please wait while newer package versions are being discovered
...
└── jquery#1.10.0 (2.0.2 now available)
```

Edit:

**a correction has been made in master branch.
The bug doesn't exists anymore https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/562**

Comment: This question is a bug and it's fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [open a ticket](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/new) about it.